# Laravel remote method is giving 404 (Not Found)error for title existed checking

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I am using Laravel framework. When I am trying to check if title already exists it is giving a 404 error. How to solve this error?

```
ServicesController.php
Controller:

public function checkEmail()
    {
        $service = Service::all()->where('title', Input::get('title'))->first();
        if ($service) {
            return Response::json(Input::get('title').'is already taken');
        } else {
            return Response::json(Input::get('title').'is available');
        }
    }
```

Routes.php:

> Route::get('checkEmail','ServicesController@checkEmail');

view(create.blade.php):

```
$("#slider-form").validate({
  rules: {
    title: {
      required: true,
      remote: {
        url: "checkEmail",
        type: "get",
      }

    },
    ar_title: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    title: {
      required: "<font color='red'>Please Enter Service Name</font>",
      remote: "<font color='red'>Service Already Exists</font>"
    },
    ar_title: {
      required: "<font color='red'>Please Enter Service Name in Arabic</font>"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: provide full url in `url: "checkEmail",`

Comment: u mean url:"www.domain.com/checkEmail"....!

Comment: open your network tab and check the url

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/checkEmail?title=r 404 (Not Found) this is giving

Comment: is your route like this `Route::get('/services/checkEmail','ServicesController@checkEmail');`?

Comment: //SERVICES ROUTING
Route::get('services', ['uses'=>'ServicesController@index']);
Route::get('services/create', 'ServicesController@create');
Route::post('services/store', 'ServicesController@store');
Route::get('services/edit/{id}','ServicesController@edit');
Route::patch('services/update/{id}', 'ServicesController@update');
Route::get('services/delete/{id}','ServicesController@delete_service');

Route::get('/checkEmail','ServicesController@checkEmail');

Comment: @arunkumar You need to just try with www.domain.com/public/checkEmail instead of www.domain.com/checkEmail

Comment: your url says `127.0.0.1:8000/services/checkEmail` and your routes have not Route like this

Comment: i am using in localhost...
http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/checkEmail?title=r  same error

Comment: @arunkumar You need to just try with localhost/projectname/public/checkEmail instead of www.domain.com/checkEmail

Comment: Just try this `url: "127.0.0.1:8000/checkEmail",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS your form is like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" name="user-form" action="{{url('services/store')}}" id="slider-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Add an route in your route file as

```
Route::post('services/store','ServicesController@checkEmail');
```

**Modified:-** Change

```
    <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" name="user-form" action="services/store"
       id="slider-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
Route::post('services/store','ServicesController@checkEmail');
```

Then try
It will work for you.

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal tasi-form" method="post" name="user-form"  
   action="{{url('services/store')}}" id="slider-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: It should go to `services/store` not `services/checkEmail` are you chane the form action url ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/store 500 (Internal Server Error)

route:Route::post('services/store','ServicesController@checkEmail');

Comment: Try the modified answer once .

Comment: Hi i tried in other way..it's working fine...anyway thank you@Bibhudatta Sahoo